# Cognito AWS- Android Signing in

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to connect sample app to my Cognito (user pool) on AWS. I follow that instruction:

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/AmazonCognitoYourUserPoolsDemo

I am able to create (sign up) new users (I can see them in my user pool ) but when  try to sign in Error message (Sign-in Failed Error) occurs on my phone. Password and username are correct.

Comment: What's your AWS SDK version? There is a bug in earlier version of the SDK which may occur on non US locale devices. Make sure you have the latest version. See https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#release-2217-05202016

Comment: Further, can you provide a stack trace for the exception you are seeing?